# CSS - prevent border from moving on scroll

Tags: html, css

When the browser window is resized, the borders are shifting away from the content?

How can I achieve a design where the border remains in one place, no matter the height of the window?

```css
.story_header {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.story_header:before,
.story_header:after {
  content: '';
  width: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  border: 2px solid black;
  margin-top: 20px;
  left: 35%;
}

.story_header:after {
  right: 35%;
  left: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class='section_1'>
  <div class="grid-x">
    <div class='large-12 cell'>
      <h2 class='story_header'>Our Story</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: This guy lol I usually don't find the need to reply back to individuals like yourself,but I couldn't resist. Lets start from the beginning of your comment.1:I'm tired, I'm sorry I misspelled a word. 2 : I was having trouble getting my code to display, which is why I just submitted the question as is .3 : hey guy, its stack overflow .I didn't know proper grammar was a must. I'm sincerely sorry for hurting you. God Bless you and I hope you find the happiness you are searching for,because any person who would deliberately go out of their way to be nasty to an individual isn't someone who is happy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to wrap the 'Our Story' to an element let's say `span` then add the pseudo elements on that `span`. Try this:

CSS:

```
.story_header{
    position:relative;
    display:flex;
    justify-content: center;
}

.story_title{
    position:relative;
}

.story_title:before, .story_title:after{
    content:'';
    width:100px;
    position:absolute;
    border:2px solid black;
    margin-top:20px;
}

.story_title:before{
    right:100%;
}

.story_title:after{
    left:100%;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="grid-x">
    <div class='large-12 cell'>
        <h2 class='story_header'> <span class="story_title">Our Story</span></h2>
    </div>
</div>
```